# can't set a property for flex container in segment widgets

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am new to Kony framework. Now i am going through Widget. There i came across Segment widgets using I would create a flex container with some labels and textbox.

My UI design are :
  1. I Created a segment and set a flex container with some labels and text box in that segment
  2. After that I turn off the flex container visible
  3. And I type a code like :

function flex()
 {
  frmAssign.sgmt1.flex1.isVisible = true;//to show flex as visible but it does not read the property of that flex
 }

In simple terms just If I click segment first row flex container isVisible should be true
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpcSU.png)

want to achieve this design in kony

Answer (score 0):

Try change `frmAssign.sgmt1.flex1.isVisible = true;`

```
frmAssign.sgmt1.flex1.setVisibility(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the widget of segment directly.

You have to create a property (eg:isVisible) in Master Data of the segment.

initial Value of this property would be "false",

Then change the value as you per your need.

Answer (score 0):

To change properties in segment data you have change the properties in array which you have set to data of segment.
Basically idea is

- if you are using masterdata then you need to read the data change
  property values and reassign.
- if you are dynamically setting data
  then you need to change that array and reassign

// always check for Null for selecteindex
//Note keep your existing properties and just change isVisible to true

```
var selecteindex= frmAssign.sgmt1.selectedRowIndex;
var segData = frmAssign.sgmt1.data[selecteindex];
segData[selecteindex] =("YourFlexName": {
            "text": "CButton1",
             "isVisible":true
        });

form1.segment1.setDataAt(segData,selecteindex);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is :

```
var selectedIndex= frmAssign.sgmt1.selectedRowIndex;
var rowData = frmAssign.sgmt1.data[selectedIndex];
rowData["flex1"]["isVisible"] = true;
form1.segment1.setDataAt(rowData, selectedIndex);
```